# Django - Template with expression

Tags: django, django-templates

In a template I'd like evaluate this expression

```
assoc = service not in backends.not_associated
```

And store it in a variable, here is the context:

```html
<ul class="list-inline">
{% for service in backends.backends %}
    {% with assoc=service not in backends.not_associated %}
    <li{% if assoc %} class="associated"{% endif %}>
        <a rel="nofollow"
            href="{% url
                'social:'|add:assoc|yesno:'begin,disconnect' service %}"
            title="{{ service|title }}">
            <img src="{% static 'social_icons/'|add:service|add:'.png' %}" />
        </a>
    </li>
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

With am I getting this error ?

> u'with' received an invalid token: u'not'

It seems `with` can't evaluate a boolean operation, can it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't evaluate expressions in django templates. To do so, you must use [custom template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/). You could use [assignment tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#assignment-tags) for your case.

Comment: Ok I see, assignment tags seems indeed to be the way to go for me. I incorrectly though that `with` was made for evaluating expressions. Thx